# Opencart Quick Checkout page not working after install the extension

Tags: javascript, php, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I transferred the Opencart default checkout page to Quick Checkout page using installing the extension.
But If I click the checkout button on cart page, it goes to the default checkout page(index.php?route=checkout/checkout).
It should be redirected to the index.php?route=quickcheckout/checkout.
How can I fix that?
(I already make the quickcheckout status as enable on admin side)

Comment: First... you should ask developer of this extension. Next... Which version of OC you are using? If you are use OC3.0.2 after you install some extension you must refresh modifications in admin and clear SASS cache also in admin dashboard.